# How to prevent Post from getting redirected in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a small site which builds a link for a selection

```
<td><a id="participant_link" href="" data-method="POST">Add</a></td>
```

using jquery

```
$(document).on("change","#participant",function(){
  $("#participant_link").attr("href", "/participations/create_new/"+$("#participant :selected").val()+"/"+$("#hi").html());
});
```

which is then fired to an action with route:

```
create_new_participation POST  /participations/create_new/:player_id /:tournament_id(.:format)      participations#create_new
```

Which code is:

```
def create_new
  @player = Player.find(params[:player_id])
  @tournament = Tournament.find(params[:tournament_id])
  @tournament.players << @player

  redirect_to "/tournaments/#{@tournament.id}/edit",status: :see_other
end
```

It should redirect to:

```
edit_tournament GET    /tournaments/:id/edit(.:format)  tournaments#edit
```

with GET method.

The problem is I get:

> No route matches [POST] "/tournaments/7/edit"

I used PUT previously and it worked, but I've cleaned up the site code (remove forms and other tags from inside of tables, find stray tags, this kind of stuff) and it stopped working.
I've read that POST is something that cannot be redirected, but lo and behold it gets redirected. I tried to use `status` for redirection, but it also didn't work.

Any ideas why does this happen and what to do to make it stop? I know that I could make tournaments#edit accept both GET and PUT, but this would be an ugly fix, not a proper solution.

Comment: Apparently your routes are out of order. `edit_tournament GET   /tournaments` doesn't look right to me. Would you mind providing your `routes.rb`?

Comment: Also, the part `redirect_to "/tournaments/#{@tournament.id}/edit"` seems like you are not using the rails-built routes in the style of `edit_tournament @tournament` and as @D-side pointed out, the problem lies most probably in your route definition (Do you use `resource` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web)?

Comment: Yep, I use it. The problem was that the jquery didn't fire until I've changed the spinner.

Sorry for taking Your, time, the answer came to me just after posting question, not couple of days before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lied in jquery which fired only after changing the #participant which is a selection box. Without it the link was empty so it routed to itself with a post action.